# UIWebView to exclude autolink for certain link

Tags: ios, uiwebview, hyperlink, detection

I have an UIWebView which auto-detects links and that's fine.

However I want to prevent it to auto-link a specific link I do not want it detected.

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's possible to manipulate the built in data detection, so you'll have to do the data detection manually with `NSDataDetector` and manipulate the webview with a `UIWebViewDelegate`.